# spring ws MessageEndpoint vs PayloadEndpoint

Tags: spring-ws

What is the difference here? Can you give an example. Thanks in advance

From the source for `PayLoadEndpoint` I see

```
Source invoke(Source request) throws Exception;
```

In `MessageEndpoint` I see

```
void invoke(MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception;
```

What is the use of both options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can make up from the javadoc, the PayloadEndpoint is used when you just want the message payload (the content of the incoming message) and MessageEndpoint is used when you need the complete MessageContext (including request/response, and so on).

Check out:
 - [PayloadEndpoint](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/PayloadEndpoint.html)
 - [MessageEndpoint](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/MessageEndpoint.html)